# Why is "excited" used to describe "anticipation"?

Tags: adjectives

> "They set out with an innocent, **excited anticipation** of the journey to come, but the five men quickly encounter reality in the form of blizzards, lighting, thirst, starvation and snakes" (An example sentence from a Chinese grammar book)

I find another source ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/theobserver/2006/dec/31/featuresreview.review1)) that may be more credible:

> But my diary is quite good on nature notes: the first time I saw a fox in the garden in 1986, the first time I saw a fox in the street, the first time I saw fox cubs in the garden, all recorded in **excited detail.**

Why is "excited" used to describe "anticipation"? I think "excit**ed**" or structures like that can only depict people. Shouldn't it be "exciting" in order to describe a thing, in this case, anticipation?

Or is metaphor used here to compare anticipation to humans? but it doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Please cite a source. Also see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/excited): "_**excited trading on the stock exchange** followed in the wake of the favorable economic report_"

Comment: The men were looking forward to their journey in an excited way, expecting it to be an enjoyable adventure. The diarist wrote notes about the foxes in an excited manner.

Comment: @KateBunting Sounds like those adjectives are not describing the following noun at all, and used like an adverb in a noun phrase.

Comment: Yes - obviously the 'detail' is not literally excited, but the writer has telescoped the sentence for the sake of brevity. The meaning is still clear.